# SSH вход одним по паролю, другим по ключу

Tags: ssh

Здравствуйте.

Возможно ли соединяться по SSH одному пользователю (к примеру администратору) по паролю, а другому (к примеру web-программисту) по ключу без надобности вводить пароль?

Если да, то подскажите куда копать.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настройте авторизацию по ключам (манов полно), публичный ключ web-программиста, положите в authorized_keys, а публичный ключ администратора не кладите в authorized_keys. Смысл в том что по дефолту идет сначала проверка ключа, если он не верный или отсутствует то спрашивается пароль.

Answer (score 1):

А можно ещё извратиться и повесить двух демонов ssh на разные порты, один из демонов настроить на авторизацию по ключу, а другой - по паролю.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте файл config в каталоге .ssh и добавьте нужные Вам ключи.

config В нём:

Host dv

HostName example.com

User domainuser

Посмотреть можно здесь:  http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1625/Using+an+SSH+Config+File